# Scite: "Go" not running compiled and built code, giving "not recognized" error

Tags: c++, scite

The "Go" function is Scite is giving me the following error

"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Is the '.' trying to relate to a path?

I have no trouble compiling and building. The exe file built works too. I just used a simple hello world code:

```
int main()
{

   cout << "Hello "  ;
   return 0;    
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've removed the "Go" tag, because your questions seems to be completely unrelated to the Go programming language.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your config file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because scite is using './' before the generated output file to execute the program and this is what we normally do to execute the programs in 'terminal' (linux). however, this is not required in windows and we just specify the output name and hit enter to execute '.exe' files.

you need to open cpp.properties in option menu and lookup the following:

```
# C++ styles
```

under the comment

```
# Braces are only matched in operator style
```

edit the line

```
command.go.*.c=./$(FileName)
```

to remove './'. Make it

```
command.go.*.c=$(FileName)
```

Again repeat the same thing below the following comment:

```
# To make the Go command both compile (if needed) and execute, use this setting:  
#command.go.needs.*.c=gcc $(ccopts) -std=c99 $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName)
```

Change

```
command.go.*.c=./$(FileName)
```

to

```
command.go.*.c=$(FileName)
```

**'make' setting**

If you are using mingW-gcc then lookup for the 'make' program in mingW-gcc installation folder. That should be 'mingw32-make'. Below the comment:

```
# Braces are only matched in operator style
```

Change

```
make.command=make
```

to

```
make.command=mingw32-make
```